# WebView Does not display

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiwebview, webview

WebView Does not display.
my code is

WebViewController.m

```
#import "WebViewController.h"

@interface WebViewController ()

@end

@implementation WebViewController

@synthesize url, webView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.webView];
    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];

    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

and in my

ViewController.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Spit out some pretty JSON for the tweet that was tapped. Neato.
    //NSString *formattedJSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[self.office objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //NSLog(@"tweet:\n%@", formattedJSON);

    NSObject *vURL = [self.office objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    self.URL =vURL;
    WebViewController * vc = [[WebViewController alloc] init];

    vc.url = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];
    NSLog(@"%@",URL);
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: when you step thru it, what is the value of vc?

Comment: what value ,vc is instance of my webview controller

Comment: Is the `URL variable the instance variable backing your `URL`? What's its value at the time you execute `vc.url = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];`? And what exactly do you mean by "won't display"? Does the controller not appear at all, or does the web page just not load?

Comment: i am just sending my object from viewcontroller from webviewcontroller.

Comment: Yes I see that. At run time, what is the valid of URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be okie. I would suggest to implement the delegate method

```
-(void) webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error{}
```

Check whether you get any error over here. You can also check whether loading has started or it has finished using the delegate.

Check whether your self.navigationController is nil or not.

[Also this link can help you if you are using https.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021902/uiwebview-wont-display-https-iphone)